# Apache (.htaccess and mod_rewrite) url rewrite/redirection not working :404 page not found error

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just installed the mod_rewrite module on my server and am trying to test it out by directing all urls to a webpage good.html

this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule .* good.html
```

however I keep getting a 404 page not found message?
I've checked my httpd.conf file and ran phpinfo() and the module seems to have loaded fine. Any ideas?

Also I am working on apache 2.0.58

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem. Everything looks fine, but I had to change two configurations on **httpd.conf** (or any other site config loaded).

Change to:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

These options are inside **Directory tag**. If you do not set AllowOverride All, .htaccess does not take effect.

Eder